# How to pair random clients with each other?

Tags: android, sockets, client

I'm making a client/server game app for android. Currently I managed to get the app working using two locally known IPs. My issue now is how do I go about making my app pair client/servers randomly.

I was thinking that initially every person starts as a client and they connect to a master server. The master server then pairs them together and specifies who will be the server and who will be the client between the two. If this is the best way to do it, how do I go about making the master server program? What kind of server do I set it up on? I'm in the dark about how to go with this.

Answer (score 0):

actually i did not answer right away thinking i would waste the night in needless fear but let us - if you don't mind - bump the issue up the hill - given just now i am going clickety-click looking for places to put up my first app - i found 2-3

let us examine the chance to do conceptual work on what is called stochastic List

given a large dataset = available apps

and another large dataset = people looking for apps

how would we code a fair presentation algorithm as some numbers like 100,000 are not out of scope but we get the same 10-20 apps on many keyclicks & not get much done - thus:

```
class Customer{}
class Application{}
Map <BigInteger,Customer>
Map <BigInteger,Application>
```

then we look into SecureRandom to pull from the application base ....

lot of work to be done but major point is to use SecureRandom rather than Math.random for several reasons ..

Comment: About 184,000,000 results for search term does not equal 20 places

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand any of what u said